# Conformal Equivalance of Sets in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Are these sets conformally equivalent, That is, is there a conformal bijection between them. $S_1=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid0<|z|<1\}$ and $S_2=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid1<|z|<2\}$?
The only thing that I could find is a theorem of (F.H. Schottky, 1877) see [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=F.H.+Schottky%2C+1877&oq=F.H.+Schottky%2C+1877&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=F.H.+Schottky%2C+1877&oq=F.H.+Schottky%2C+1877&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.60512.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c..2.serp.gsI3-y4kiHs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.cGE&fp=ce8e585f1afc8fe7&biw=1024&bih=513) (the first search result).

I don't know if I could use the theorem for these sets because I have zero in one of them. 
 And also we did not learn this theorem in class.
The question is could the theorem be applied in this case? How can I answer this question without this theorem? Any ideas?Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion for getting started: Suppose $f:S_1\to S_2$ is analytic.  What can you say about the isolated singularity at $0$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I'm not sure what do you mean. Are you suggesting they are equivalent?

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded, the singularity of $f$ at $z=0$ must be removable. Try to take it from there.

Comment: @mrf Ok, Than you.

Answer (score 3):

I like the suggestion by Meyer. Suppose $f: S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is biholomorphic. Then it is bounded and has a removable singularity at $0$. Therefore, $f$ can be extended to a analytic map on the unit disk centered at the origin. This is a contradiction as no point near $S_2$ can be the image of $0$.

Comment: So are you saying that if $f$ can't be extended to the open unit disk and still be 1-1? but does that imply the the sets are not equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mapping which sends $|z|$ to $|z|+1$ and maintains the angle will do. You're just blowing-up the punctured disk into an annulus. I haven't worked out the details, but it seems plausible.

**Added 2-9-13** Follow-up on why my conjecture fails:

$$ f(z) = (|z|+1)\frac{z}{|z|} $$

is this map I indicated. If $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$ then for $z \neq 0$,

$$ f(z) = \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{z\bar{z}}} \right)z $$. Clearly the above expression has nontrivial $\bar{z}$-dependence and as such cannot be holomorphic (hence not conformal). If you prefer, $z=x+iy$ we have
$$f=u+iv \ \ \& \  \ u(x,y) = x\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) \ \ \& \ \ 
v(x,y) = y\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) $$
and $u_y = v_x$ hence the Cauchy-Riemann equations are violated by my mapping (everywhere) and this map is not complex-differentiable, analytic, holomorphic, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to fill the details.

Comment: I could be wrong!

Comment: This map is not holomorphic.

Comment: There is no way to work out the details here